# Why does a vertical scrollbar appear on this JS plugin which automatically resizes the height of a div to fill the remaining space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout

I have developed a jQuery plugin which helps you resize the height of an element in order to make it fill the available space inside its parent.

Basically, the idea was to create some "keyword" classes, and with the following HTML structure:

```
 <body>
        <div class="si-block">
            <div class="si-level">Header</div>
            <div class="si-level-fluid-height">Content</div>
            <div class="si-level">Footer</div>
        </div>        
    </body>
```

You are saying that **si-level-fluid-height** should take the remaining space inside of the `si-block` container. The height is calculated by making the difference of all the other `si-level` elements inside the same `si-block` and the available height inside the `si-block` element (which has 100% height of its parent). Therefore, if `html` and `body` have `height: 100%`, that means, take the remaining available space of the viewport.

Below, all the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Si JS</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function($) {   

    /*
     * Object which maps a selector code to its CSS selector counterpart.
     * 
     * @type Object
     */
    var SI_SELECTORS = {
        'SI_BLOCK': '.si-block', // Full height and width block element class.
        'SI_LEVEL': '.si-level', // Auto height and width block level element class.
        'SI_LEVEL_FLUID': '.si-level-fluid', // Fluid height and width block level element class.
        'SI_LEVEL_FLUID_HEIGHT': '.si-level-fluid-height', // Fluid height only block level element class.
        'SI_LEVEL_FLUID_WIDTH': '.si-level-fluid-width' // Fluid width only block level element class.
    };

    /*
     * Object which maps a data attribute's code to its jQuery '.data()' parameter counterpart.
     * 
     * @type Object
     */
    var SI_DATA_ATTRIBUTES = {
        'SI_LEVEL_MIN_HEIGHT':  'siMinHeight'
    };

    /*
     * jQuery plugins.
     */    
    /**
     * Check if a data-* attribute exists on a jQuery object.
     * 
     * @param {String} dataAttribute The data-* attribute to check.
     * @returns {Boolean} True if the attribute exists, false otherwise.
     */
    $.fn.hasDataAttribute = function(dataAttribute) {        
        return this.data().hasOwnProperty(dataAttribute);
    };

    /**
     * Find all the elements matching the specified selector which are not nested inside another element matching
     * another selector inside the current jQuery set.
     * 
     * @param {String} selector A jQuery selector for the elements to search for.
     * @param {String} notWithinSelector A jQuery selector which will make the method exclude the elements matched 
     *                                                       by selector if the elements are within an element matched by this selector.
     * @returns {jQuery} A jQuery object representing the set of the elements found.
     */
    $.fn.findNotWithin = function(selector, notWithinSelector) {         
         var context = this[0];
         var $notWithinElements = this.find(selector).filter(function() {
             return $(this).parent().closest(notWithinSelector, context).length === 0;
        });
        return $notWithinElements;
    };

   /**
    * Get the selector for the specified selector code.
    * 
    * @param {String} selectorCodeName The string code of the Si selector.
    * @returns {String} The selector's string.
    */
    function getSelector(selectorCodeName) {
        return SI_SELECTORS[selectorCodeName];
    }

    /**
     * Get the data-* attribute's name as jQuery's '.data()' parameter.
     * 
     * @param {String} attributeCodeName The attribute code name.
     * @returns {String} The attribute name as jQuery's '.data()' parameter.
     */
    function getDataAttributeName(attributeCodeName) {
        return SI_DATA_ATTRIBUTES[attributeCodeName];
    }

    /**
     * Resize the Si's blocks.
     * 
     * @param {jQuery} $siBlocks The jQuery object which contains a set of Si blocks.
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    function resizeSiBlocks($siBlocks) {
        $siBlocks.each(function() {
            resizeSiBlockLevels($(this));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Resize the Si's levels of a Si block.
     *  
     * @param {jQuery} $siBlock The jQuery object of a Si block.
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    function resizeSiBlockLevels($siBlock) {
        var resizeRoutine = function($siBlock) {
            var siBlockSelector = getSelector('SI_BLOCK');
            var siLevelSelector = getSelector('SI_LEVEL');
            var siFluidHeightLevelSelector = getSelector('SI_LEVEL_FLUID_HEIGHT');

            // The levels of a block which don't have fluid height and are not nested inside another block.
            var $siNotFluidHeightBlockLevels = $siBlock.findNotWithin(siLevelSelector, siBlockSelector);

            // The levels of a block which have fluid height and are not nested inside another block.
            var $siFluidHeightBlockLevels = $siBlock.findNotWithin(siFluidHeightLevelSelector, siBlockSelector);

            var blockOuterHeight = $siBlock.outerHeight();
            var blockHeight = $siBlock.height();
            var totalNotFluidLevelsHeight = (function() {
                var totalHeight = 0;
                $siNotFluidHeightBlockLevels.each(function() {
                    totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
                });
                return totalHeight;
            })();

            // Resizing the height of '.si-level-fluid-height'.
            var availableHeightForFluidBlockLevels = blockHeight - totalNotFluidLevelsHeight;
            var siFluidHeightBlockLevelsCount = $siFluidHeightBlockLevels.length;
            var defaultAvailableHeightPerFluidBlockLevel = availableHeightForFluidBlockLevels / siFluidHeightBlockLevelsCount;

            var minSiLevelsHeight = 0;
            $siFluidHeightBlockLevels.each(function() {

                var $fluidHeightLevel = $(this);            

                var minHeightAttributeName = getDataAttributeName('SI_LEVEL_MIN_HEIGHT');
                if ($fluidHeightLevel.hasDataAttribute(minHeightAttributeName)) {
                    minSiLevelsHeight += $fluidHeightLevel.data(minHeightAttributeName);
                }

                $fluidHeightLevel.outerHeight(defaultAvailableHeightPerFluidBlockLevel);
            });

            var blockExtraHeight = blockOuterHeight - blockHeight; // borders
            $siBlock.css({'min-height' : (minSiLevelsHeight + totalNotFluidLevelsHeight + blockExtraHeight) + 'px' });
        };
        resizeRoutine($siBlock);

        /*
         * Fix the height even for some dinamically content loaded asynchronously.
         */
        setTimeout(function() {
            resizeRoutine($siBlock);
        }, 0);
    }    

    /* 
     * Si's public API.
     * */
    var Si = {
      resizeBlocks:  function() {
          resizeSiBlocks($(getSelector('SI_BLOCK')));
      }
    };           
    window.Si = Si;

    /*
     * Bind a resize event to the window object when the document is ready. Custom events must be handled separately.     
     */
    $(function() {

        /* Block levels height handling. */
        $(window).resize(function() {
            resizeSiBlocks($(getSelector('SI_BLOCK')));
        }).resize(); // And trigger a resize event immediately so that blocks get resized correctly.

    });

})(window.jQuery);
        </script>
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            /*
            * .si-block is a block container with full height.
            */
            .si-block {   
                display: block;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            /*
             * .si-level is a block container with height set to auto (its content makes its height).
             */
            .si-block .si-level {    
                height: auto;
            }

            /* Both .si-block and a .si-level inside of it have a 'border-box' box-sizing */
            .si-block, .si-block .si-level, .si-block .si-level-fluid-height {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="si-block">
            <div class="si-level">Header</div>
            <div class="si-level-fluid-height">Content</div>
            <div class="si-level">Footer</div>
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the rendered page:

[image]

Note that `Footer` is always at the bottom cause `Content` takes the available space automatically calculated by the plugin.

The thing I don't like is that when you scroll up `content` is resized, but sometimes a vertical scrollbar appears and disappears instantly, telling me that maybe there's something wrong in my calculation:

[image]

But I just can't see where is the issue in the code. Do you guys have an idea? This appearing-disappearing vertical scrollbar is a bit annoying.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Hi, please read this: [mcve]  While sometimes additional code can be relevant, in this case there appears to be far too much unrelated code.

Comment: It should be possible to do this with just css.   The scrollbar appearing is likely due to a delay in the browser/js sync, which is why css alone would not cause this.

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry, I don't agree with you. The code I posted is the minimum needed to reproduce the same behaviour I see on my browser. I only posted the code of the plugin and a trivial HTML structure.

Comment: Yes, I now there's flexbox and other CSS only techniques. But I was looking for a more cross browser solution with JS. What do you think? Can I somehow patch this "bug? due to the delay between this browser/JS sync?